# Integrating HTML pages to laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, integration

I integrated HTML template with multiple pages to my laravel project. The main page is working finely but when I click the links in the main page it isn't opening the other html pages. But when I type the URL the page is opening up.
Some of my routes code is as follows :

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('icons', function()
{
    return view('icons');
});

Route::get('404', function()
{
    return view('404');
});

Route::get('500', function()
{
    return view('500');
});

Route::get('accordion', function()
{
    return view('accordion');
});

Route::get('alerts', function()
{
    return view('alerts');
});

Route::get('avatar', function()
{
    return view('avatar');
});

Route::get('background', function()
{
    return view('background');
});

Route::get('badge', function()
{
    return view('badge');
});

Route::get('blog', function()
{
    return view('blog');
});

Route::get('border', function()
{
    return view('border');
});
```

These are the HTML pages, I convert it to `.blade.php` extension :

[image]

An example for the links in my main page is as follows :

```
<li class="side-item side-item-category">General</li>
                        <li class="slide">
                            <a class="side-menu__item" href="icons.html"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="side-menu__icon"  viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 4c-4.42 0-8 3.58-8 8s3.58 8 8 8 8-3.58 8-8-3.58-8-8-8zm3.5 4c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5s-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5.67-1.5 1.5-1.5zm-7 0c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5S9.33 11 8.5 11 7 10.33 7 9.5 7.67 8 8.5 8zm3.5 9.5c-2.33 0-4.32-1.45-5.12-3.5h1.67c.7 1.19 1.97 2 3.45 2s2.76-.81 3.45-2h1.67c-.8 2.05-2.79 3.5-5.12 3.5z" opacity=".3"/><circle cx="15.5" cy="9.5" r="1.5"/><circle cx="8.5" cy="9.5" r="1.5"/><path d="M12 16c-1.48 0-2.75-.81-3.45-2H6.88c.8 2.05 2.79 3.5 5.12 3.5s4.32-1.45 5.12-3.5h-1.67c-.69 1.19-1.97 2-3.45 2zm-.01-14C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"/></svg><span class="side-menu__label">Icons</span><span class="badge badge-danger side-badge">New</span></a>
                        </li>
```

When I enter `http://localhost:8000/icons` the icons page is opening up.

My pages are inside views folder and assets are into the public folder. Can somebody help me on fixing this??

Comment: I think it is better if you show us your links from the first page.

Comment: Paste the ```links in the main page``` and ```the URL``` you type

Comment: I added it. Thank you @linktoahref

Comment: Quick note: Laravel supports [View Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#view-routes). You could write `Route::view('/', 'welcome');` or `Route::view('badge', 'badge');` to shorten your routes

Comment: links added @KeithMifsud. Thank you.

Comment: `href="icons.html"` should be `href="icons"` (your route is `icons`) or change your routes to include `.html`: `Route::get('icons.html', function() { return view('icons'); });`

Comment: what does badge do? @kerbh0lz

Comment: First parameter to `Route::view` is the `route`, second is the `view` to open. Another example (including `.html`) would be `Route::view('icons.html', 'icons');`

Comment: @kerbh0lz Still not working. I edit the href but in my browser it shoes icons.html again in the URL  box

Comment: still my URL box shows as follows : `http://localhost:8000/icons.html`

Comment: So, please make this clear: do you want your pages to have `.html` endings or not?

Comment: That isn't the problem. I just want to have them open in clicking. even after editing the href code my page isn't opening up. That's what I mentioned above @kerbh0lz

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again. Or open it with another browser

Comment: That also didn't work @STA

Comment: If a link `<a href="/icons">Icons</a>` opens `http://localhost:8000/icons.html` in your browser there might be something going on in the background that we don't know about, server-rewriting or a Javascript redirecting - or you might be editing the wrong file/link. Use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see which url gets called and if there's redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Replace href="icons.html" with href="{{ route('icons') }}" // Route name that you have assigned in the web.php // Route file.

Use For icons      =  href="{{ route('icons') }}"
Use For accordion  =  href="{{ route('accordion') }}"
Use For avatar     =  href="{{ route('avatar') }}"
Use For background =  href="{{ route('background') }}"
```

Comment: There are no route names though

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert
href="icons.html" to href="{{ url('icons') }}" and it will work.

When anytime you want to redirect to any page you must either used "url" or "route" (if you have specified name to route).

Answer (score -1):

Your link to icons.html is wrong. This should be:

```html
 <a class="side-menu__item" href="{{url('/icons')}}"></a>
```

Comment: still not working. Even after editing the href, when I click the link the URL box indicating it as icons.html

Comment: If you have swapped icons.html to icons in your href attribute and refreshed, it will not show icons.html in the address bar.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. I saved it. But it isn't working.

Comment: How is it not working? What is the error / behaviour you are seeing (in detail please)?

Comment: I changed the href as mentioned above. Still it returns 404 not found error. And Url box indicates it as icons.html even now.

Comment: Please paste your updated anchor tag here as it is not possible that the address bar shows the .HTML suffix if you're not adding it unless you have some specific web server configs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218502/discussion-between-nithur-and-keith-mifsud).